# Call functions of the created threads periodically (Manual scheduling)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have created 10 threads (pthreads to be precise), each thread is registered with a call back functions say fn1, fn2 ...fn10. I am also assigning different priorities for each thread with scheduling policy FIFO. The requirement of the application is that each of these functions have to be called periodically (periodicity varies for each thread). To implement the periodicity, I got ideas from other questions to use itimer and sigwait methods (Not very sure if this is good way to implement this, Any other suggestion to implement this are welcome).

My question is how do I need handle SIGALRM to repeatedly call these functions in their respective threads when periodicity is varying for each thread?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Do sleep functions sleep all threads or just the one who call it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11915292/3545273) as a reference, my advice would be to avoid SIGALRM. Signals are normally delivered to a process.

IMHO you have two ways to do that :

- implement a clever monitor that knows about all threads periodicity. It computes the time at which it must wake a thread, sleeps to that time, wakes the thread and continuouly iterates on that. Pro : threads only wait on a semaphore or other mutex, con : the monitor it too clever for me
- each thread knows its periodicity, and stores its last start time. When it finishes its job, it computes how long it should wait until next activation time and sleeps for that duration. Pro : each thread is fully independant and implementation looks easy, cons : you must ensure that in your implementation, `sleep` calls only blocks calling thread.

I would use the 2nd solution, because the first looks like a user level implementation of `sleep` in a threaded environment.

Comment: Thanks, I shall try 2nd solution and come up with result.

Comment: 2nd solution works good enough. `nanosleep` blocks only the calling thread.